# How do I disabled HttpRequestValidation on HttpRequestBase?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, httprequest

I have an MVC project in which a filter checks for a parameter from the request params.

```
request.Params["Username"]
```

But if the request contains illegal characters then the params property throws a HttpRequestValidationException exception.

So I have to catch this exception then access the params property which works fine.

How do disable the validation on this request which is arriving into a helper class as HttpRequestBase? I don't want to globally do this for every request, just when it arrives into this class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Jon-S comments, UnvalidatedRequestValues is how you can bypass validation for a single value. In this example, it would be:

```
request.Unvalidated["Username"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing more of your code, I can't be sure, but it sounds like you can just put the request in a try-catch.

```
try
{
    ...
    request.Params["Username"]
    ...
}
catch (HttpRequestValidationException ex)
{
    //your error handling goes here.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and welcome to StackOverflow!  The question indicates that they are already catching and handling the exception - they were asking about a per-handler way to disable validation entirely, in the framework.  Do you know of such a thing?

Comment: I see what you mean. I think you can use the UnvalidatedRequestValues class to accomplish what you're looking for. You can utilize it on the form or per item. There's more information here. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.unvalidatedrequestvalues(v=vs.110).aspx

Hope that answers your question!